# wait intil iframe content contains

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a function that refreshes iframe content when button is clicked.

```
  function changeContent(){
      iframe.newContent(); 
      // wait until content contains string "hey"
      return true; 
  }
```

I want to use while loop, how can i make the function wait on the string until returning true?
This is how I access the iframe now:

```
var MyIFrame = document.getElementById("myframe");
var MyIFrameDoc = (MyIFrame.contentWindow || MyIFrame.contentDocument);
if (MyIFrameDoc.document) MyIFrameDoc = MyIFrameDoc.document;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `onload` event.
JS:

```
function load()
{
   alert("Frame is loaded");
}
```

HTML:

```
<iframe src="frame_a.htm" onload="load()">
```

Besides, it is not recommended to bind an event handler directly in HTML like above (it is just for illustration). It is better to use something like `iframe.onload` or  [`addEventlistener`/`attachEvent`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)

While loop will freeze your webpage as JS is always executed in one thread

Comment: I don't need to detect it the first time it loads, but after user clicks the button iframe will go to different page and I need to detect if the string is present on that second page. will load event get triggered again when this happens? Thanks

Comment: onload event is fired any time iframe content is loaded. You can add an event handler before you change a `src` of an iframe. And it will not be fiered after first time iframe is loaded with a page

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
iframe.onload = function () {
};
```